# How to make objects independent?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

In Cycles, I imported a car, which a bunch of parts (in .obj format) I assembled together.

For some reason, when I apply a shader to one part, it does the same to  a bunch of other objects, like the ones with the same color or property.

Could be because in this editor where I put the vehicle together, all the object's names are the same or something?

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple materials to an object which I believe will help, do the following:

1. Select different faces.
   [image]

[image]

2. After preparing your various materials, select a material and press "apply."
   [image]
3. Tadaa!
   [image]

I really hope that helps. :)

Comment: That wasn't what I wanted. I have actual objects, not faces, and when I apply a material to ONE, it does it to all the others for some reason. I only want it to apply to one object

Comment: That's because all of your objects are sharing the same material. Add a new one on your objects

Comment: Binary Green, all the Objects will have faces when you enter Edit Mode:press the Tab key.  Then use Ctrl+Tab->Face to activate Face Select mode.  There is also a button in the header to do this.  Look at the right side of all the images posted.  They have two materials listed, a blue one and a red one.  That is how you control what materials are attached to the various parts.  They are not assigned per object, they assigned per face.  This was done automatically for you upon import but now it's up to you to re-define them manually.